# Some properties can't be filtered on Elasticsearch 7.4. How to filter them?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 7.4 and I'm a newbie of elasticsearch

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "endpoint.OptOut": "NONE" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

if I search using above, it returns this

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 10,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "pinpoint-2020-05-18",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "49607119956414053843418396197478865586643200066386395138.0",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "event_type" : "event.click",
          "event_timestamp" : 1589814810000,
          "arrival_timestamp" : 1589814810554,
          "event_version" : "3.1",
          "application" : {
            "app_id" : "c6504a2cca654c0f8415184859857fdc",
            "cognito_identity_pool_id" : "",
            "sdk" : { },
            "version_code" : "11111111"
          },
          "client" : {
            "client_id" : "email-a",
            "cognito_id" : ""
          },
          "device" : {
            "platform" : { }
          },
          "session" : { },
          "endpoint" : {
            "ChannelType" : "EMAIL",
            "Address" : "=ABAQ8rfmFOeZTLCgRSb7iCsfN2uov27mPh1qz9tvksP57O1D6M9u0AaUDdmXjU1/6n+D1n5acqejpSf55a0Uq07AgrSZaE/5RfT90PHtui1J3Jc=",
            "EndpointStatus" : "ACTIVE",
            "OptOut" : "NONE",
            "EffectiveDate" : "2020-05-18T13:34:47.527Z",
            "ApplicationId" : "c6504a2cca654c0f8415184859857fdc",
            "Id" : "email-a",
            "CohortId" : "35",
            "CreationDate" : "2020-05-18T13:34:47.527Z"
          },
          "awsAccountId" : "123456123456"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So you can see there is 'NONE' in endpoint.OptOut field.

But when I search using below json,,,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"term": {"endpoint.OptOut": "NONE"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

it returns nothing...
it only returns below

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 10,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

I don't know why 'endpoint.OptOut' can't be filtered..
Some properties can be filtered, like application.app_id, endpoint.EffectiveDate, etc.
But some properties can't be filtered like 'client.client_id', 'endpoint.OptOut', etc..

Here's my mapping.

```
{
  "pinpoint-2020-05-18" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "application" : {
          "properties" : {
            "app_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "cognito_identity_pool_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "sdk" : {
              "type" : "object"
            },
            "version_code" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "arrival_timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "epoch_millis"
        },
        "attributes" : {
          "properties" : {
            "campaign_activity_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "campaign_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "campaign_send_status" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "campaign_send_status_code" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "campaign_send_status_message" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "feedback" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "treatment_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "awsAccountId" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "client" : {
          "properties" : {
            "client_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "cognito_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "client_context" : {
          "properties" : {
            "custom" : {
              "properties" : {
                "endpoint" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "legacy_identifier" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "device" : {
          "properties" : {
            "platform" : {
              "type" : "object"
            }
          }
        },
        "endpoint" : {
          "properties" : {
            "Address" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ApplicationId" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ChannelType" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "CohortId" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "CreationDate" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "EffectiveDate" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "EndpointStatus" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "OptOut" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "event_timestamp" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "event_type" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "event_version" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "facets" : {
          "properties" : {
            "email_channel" : {
              "properties" : {
                "mail_event" : {
                  "properties" : {
                    "delivery" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "processing_time_millis" : {
                          "type" : "long"
                        },
                        "recipients" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "reporting_mta" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "smtp_response" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "mail" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "common_headers" : {
                          "properties" : {
                            "date" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "from" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "subject" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "to" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "destination" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "from_address" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "headers" : {
                          "properties" : {
                            "name" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "value" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "headers_truncated" : {
                          "type" : "boolean"
                        },
                        "message_id" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "message_send_timestamp" : {
                          "type" : "long"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "open" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "ip_address" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "user_agent" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "send" : {
                      "type" : "object"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "session" : {
          "type" : "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know, why some properties can't be filtered..
and how to filter it..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here.

1. `bool.filter` is the same as `bool.must` except that the scoring [is not affected](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context). So the error is not because of `filter` but because of point 2.
2. `term` is used for exact matching. Since your `OptOut` field has (I assume) the default [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) applied, it's been lowercased behind the curtains and that's why you don't see any matches. Luckily, ES generated the `keyword` field too so you can do

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"term": {"endpoint.OptOut.keyword": "NONE"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which should return results.

Note that the above requires exact, case sensitive keywords to filter against.

Comment: really thanks..
"endpoint.OptOut":"none" works, and also "endpoint.OptOut.keyword":"NONE" does also work.
As I tried to search several properties using filter, some of these work but the others not work. If is doesn't work then I put ".keyword" at postfix, then it does work.
I want to know why some properties work and the others doesn't work without putting '.keyword' (I use lowercase) ?

Comment: especially 'client.client_id' doesn't work if I doesn't put '.keyword' as postfix.

Comment: Oh... I got to know.. if value contains symbols like '-', '+' then it can't be filtered without '.keyword'